# This is an invalid script resource request. ~/scriptresource.axd

Tags: asp.net, web-config

> **Error**  at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)

I am getting the above error from a production server.
We have six production servers and we get the above error from **three production servers only**.
Remaining three are working fine.

We have following setting for machinKey in all six servers. Path :

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config.comments
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config.comments

**OLD Setting:**

```
< machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" 
  decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" 
  validation="SHA1" 
  decryption="Auto" 
  compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" / >
```

**CHANGED TO SPECIFIC KEY**

```
< machineKey validationKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
  decryptionKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
  validation="SHA1" 
  decryption="AES" 
  compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" />
```

but getting same exception.

Can any one please tell me what could be the exact problem?

Answer (score 3):

This can be caused by search engines crawling through your pages. Sometimes they hit the ScriptResource.axd file and generate the error you are seeing.

If you can log the IPs that are causing this error, look them up and see where/who they are.

Of course, if you are only getting this from 3 of 6 servers in your web farm, something else could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but solution you provided is not working?